# The topology of uniform convergence on compact subsets of $\mathbb R$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, reference-request, uniform-convergence

Can someone give me a reference for detailed properties on **topology of uniform convergence on each compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$**?

Comment: I assume you mean $C(\Bbb R)$ with the topology generated by semi-norms $\|f\|_K:= \sup_{x\in K} |f(x)|$, for all compact K. I don't have a reference, and I don't think this space is particularly famous. Here are some more or less trivial properties for the time being: The space does not have a norm. It has a positive cone and thus a partial ordering. It has the structure of a topological ring and a topological $\Bbb C$ algebra. It is not separable. It contains the normed spaces $C_0(\Bbb R)$ and $C_c(\Bbb R)$ as topologically embedded subspaces. The uniform structure of the space is complete.

Comment: A general reference could be "Rings of Continuous Functions" by Gillman and Jerison. One of the spaces they study is $C(X)$ for $X$ locally compact Hausdorff. This space can be given various topologies, including that of uniform convergence on compacta. If you study the book and replace $X$ with $\Bbb R$ you may find guidance on whatever it is you want to do.

Comment: Look up compact-open topology. The wikipedia page has some references, Kelley being a classic one.